# How do osm2pgrouting and osm2po differ in their ways creation?

Tags: osm2po, osm2pgrouting

How do osm2po and osm2pgrouting differ in their algorithms for creating their `ways` table ?  I've seen significant differences between their processing of the same osm extract.

Processing the same file (us-midwest-latest.osm) from geofabrik using both `osm2po` and `osm2pgrouting` (and using config for cars only with both) resulted in nearly 400K more entries in the `ways` table from `osm2pgrouting` than in the corresponding `*_2po_4pgr` table.

Does osm2pgrouting just create more nodes/vertices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After analyzing my dataset more with `QGIS` I think I've found most of the differences.

Using osm2pgrouting with mapconfig_for_cars.xml still includes vertices related to pedestrian interaction, whereas osm2po with `wtr.finalMask = car` does not.

Here is a view of OSM of an intersection with crosswalks...
[image: OSM Data with Crosswalks]

Here is a view of my dataset (which is roads only) in QGIS of the same intersection... 
[image: QGIS Data]

The smaller blue vertices come from osm2pgrouting and they include the vertices for pedestrian `crossings`, whereas the larger green vertices, generated from osm2po, only contain street and rail `crossings`.

Likely, amending the configuration of level_crossing in the oms2po.config to include bike & foot would cause the disparity to drop significantly.

```
# very special hint for level_crossing modification

wtr.shuttleTrainMask = rail|car
```

Also, I have seen that the little used road type `tertiary_link` is in use in places as well, so I'll be adding that to my osm2po.config to get those segments to appear in my `ways` table.

Comment: Hmmmm... `tertirary_link` is no official tag, but I'm afraid, I've got to add it to the default config (next version). hmm.... `shuttleTrainMask` is a very delicate thing in **osm2po**. It's been introduced to distinguish links connecting road an rail, which in my opinion is a big OSM nuisance. **osm2po** uses this hint to decouple/disconnect them by assigning different vertex-ids but leaves them untouched if rail resolves to shuttleTrain.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be heavily in use, even though I can't quite wrap my head around what it's supposed to be.  Processing the north american extract, there are 14961 segments in my 'ways' table that are categorized as `tertiary_link`